# Maven ${project.version} doesn't show up in java

Tags: java, maven, environment-variables

I have a `.properties` file in `src/main/resources` and `A=${project.version}, B=...` in there. When I make a rest call, the response shows me `${project.version}` instead of the value of this environment variable. I added such file in `src/main/resources` and included them in `pom.xml`.

```
<parent>
  <groupId>service</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
 </parent>

<build> 
 <resources>
   <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
   </resource>
  </resources>
</build>
```

By getting `${project.version}`, I assume at least the call reaches this file and can get what assigned to A. I think there must be something wrong with my `pom`. Any idea? I have been stuck on this for almost 24 hours. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In `src/main/source`? Not `src/main/resources`?

Comment: You wouldn't happen to be using Spring Boot, would you?

Comment: So are you saying that, after the Maven build has ran, the file `target/classes/your.properties` doesn't contain the actual version replaced? This should work, unless the tokens `${...}` are being redefined somewhere.

Comment: Yes. It's not redefined anywhere else, actually i used the same way in previous projects and they all worked. The only difference is i changed some bean names, like from restMessage to AbcRestMessage, which i don't think should be the cause.

Comment: Well, we're now entering the *this is not possible and this must work* territory. With your config, running `mvn clean package` for example will result (by default) in a `target/classes` directory containing your properties file correctly replaced; make sure you do all of those steps (notably the `clean` part). If it still fails to replace after that, you'll need to post more info (your POM and relevant files).

Comment: It still doesn't work. But when i run the mvn clean install, the project version shows up on terminal

Comment: So, please post all your pom.xml because what you have posted should worked correctly. I can't reproduce your problem because i have not your entire pom.xml