# Maven ${project.version} not working

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, environment-variables

I would like to extract the version code from maven within my java app. I created a application.properties file with a property which calls ${project.version} and added the following to the pom file

```
<resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
</resource>
```

, very similar to this question - [Maven ${project.version} doesn't show up in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232486/maven-project-version-doesnt-show-up-in-java)

However the difference here is I am using spring boot. When I run the application the output is "${project.version}" and in the target/application.properties file, I can see that the property has not been updated with the version number.

Any ideas?

UPDATE - files and code I am using

application.properties file

```
application.version=${project.version}
```

getting the property

```
public String getVersionTest() {
        String resourceName = "application.properties"; // could also be a constant
        ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        try(InputStream resourceStream = loader.getResourceAsStream(resourceName)) {
            props.load(resourceStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return props.getProperty("application.version");
    }


System.out.println("version number = " + kiosk.getVersionTest());
output = ${project.version}
```

Comment: try the property without the "" in the application.properties file. E.g. mvn.version=${project.version}

Comment: @Edwin - sadly it didnt work. I will post all the files and code i have

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [spring boot documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven)

> since the default config files accept Spring style placeholders
>   (${…​}) the Maven filtering is changed to use @..@ placeholders (you
>   can override that with a Maven property resource.delimiter).

You have two options to achieve the desired behaviour :
Either use the @..@ syntax to specify place holder. E.g.

```
application.version=@project.version@
```

or revert back the resource filter delimiter by using property `${resource.delimiter}` as mentioned in ryanp's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42811091/1700467).

Answer (score 3):

`spring-boot-starter-parent` sets the resources plugin delimiter to `@` rather than the default `${*}` - you can override this with the `${resource.delimiter}` property.

Comment: do you mean something like this:

application.version=${resource.delimiter}

in my application.properties file?